# How to implement password strength like in gmail registration in YII php?

Tags: php, yii, passwords, yii-extensions

I want to create Password Strength Meter.I am following the [estrongpassword For YII](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/estrongpassword) I used Estrongpassword extension. I put this extension in extension folder and wrote the code as below:

```
<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
<?php

$this->widget('ext.EStrongPassword.EStrongPassword',
    array('form'=>$form, 'model'=>$model, 'attribute'=>'password'));

?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
```

when i checked my file its thorughs me ERROR as written below:

```
Alias "ext.EStrongPassword.EStrongPassword" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.
```

I wondering how to configure it,please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct and shouldn't cause any problems. Here are a few things you can try:

- Make sure you've installed the extension correctly
- Check that the spelling in file names and class name is correct. Linux is case sensitive.
- Check your extension folder `protected/extensions` and make sure that the directory `EStrongPassword` (case sensitive) exists
- Make sure the path is correct (`ext` in your script refers to `protected/extensions` path)

The file should be at:

```
protected/extensions/EStrongPassword/EStrongPassword.php
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you provide me steps to install extension as i am new to YII may be i am not installing the extension correctly.

Comment: Please follow the steps in the documentation for installing [Yii Extensions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.use). Once you've set up the extension, read my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

I was researching another problem when I came across this, perhaps it could help you.  It is a guide on custom validation rules but it uses exactly what you are looking for as an example...

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/